# Action listener java problems

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Ok so im working on a game and right now i have an image and im trying to place buttons under the image in specific places so when the user clicks that part of the screen the image changes. I am having trouble trying to figure out how to format my program for the action listener.

```
public class TestJFrame{
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private static JButton buttons[] = new JButton[4];

    private static int[][] location = new int[3][4];


    public static void main(String args[]){
        frame.getInsets().set(20, 5, 5, 5);

        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(507, 528));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Test");

        buttons[0] = new JButton("jbZero");
        buttons[1] = new JButton("jbOne"); 
        buttons[2] = new JButton("jbTwo");
        buttons[3] = new JButton("jbThree");

        frame.add(buttons[0]);
        frame.add(buttons[1]);
        frame.add(buttons[2]);
        frame.add(buttons[3]);

        setButtons();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        buttons[0].setLocation(100, 100);
    }


    private static void setButtons(){
        for (int i=0;i<=3;i++){
            buttons[i].setSize(10, 10);
            buttons[i].setLocation(0, 0);
            buttons[i].setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public void intializeListener(){
        buttons[0].addActionListener((ActionListener) this);        
    }

    public void buttonsZeroActionPreformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("button zero works");
    }
}
```

So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what do you want to implement in the listener:

1. If they do the same action you implement the listener inside `setButtons` function:

   ```
   private static void setButtons(){
       for (int i=0;i<=3;i++){
           buttons[i].setSize(10, 10);
           buttons[i].setLocation(0, 0);
           buttons[i].setVisible(true);

           buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // listener implement btn 0
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```
2. If each button need unique implementation I think that better implementation will be in a new function `setBtnListeners` and call it from your main after using `setButtons();`:

   ```
   private static void setBtnListeners() {
        buttons[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 // listener implement btn 0
            }
        });
   }
   ```

**Update:** Sorry i'd just noticed you have four buttons... you can just add another one :)